# VBA Listing variable length string in msgbox and finding cells relative to others

Tags: excel, vba

I have created a function meant to simulate a card game involving points. After playing, the final amount of points for each player is logged in a table 3 cells right of the players name. I am currently trying to create a function which is able to read the table, locate the highest value in said table, and then detect the name of the winning player(s) 3 cells left of the value and congratulate them with a msgbox.

I have currently constructed a function able to find the maximum value in a range, as well as count the # of people with matching scores (different messagebox in this scenario adjusted for grammar). However, the function cannot locate WHERE the cell is. I also have no clue on VBA's abilities of finding cells relative to others. Heres what i have atm.

```
Sub Name_Winner()

Dim Rng As String <-- takes the range of the table listing the players + values
Dim winners As Integer <-- the number of people with the highest score
Dim winnumber As Integer <-- the highest score in the table
Rng = "L2:L" & 2 + Players

'Find # of winners
winnumber = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(range(Rng))
winners = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(range(Rng), winnumber)
Cells(8, 8) = winners <--place holder, not in final code

If winners = 1 Then
    MsgBox (PLAYER NAME & " has won with " & winumber & " points!")
ElseIf winners > 1 Then
    MsgBox (PLAYER1 + PLAYER2 +.... & " have won with " & winumber & " points!")
End If

End Sub
```

I currently do not understand VBA enough to name any commands able to list a variable amount of people in a string, as well as read a cells value relative to another cell. Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: If you're using a function (which you are via Application.WorksheetFunction) that returns a value that IS NOT the cell address then yes, you have no way of knowing where that value came from.  You need to loop through each row/column/cell and from there, you can get the cells that you then need to offset and write to.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should help but you'll need to adjust it accordingly.  I haven't taken all of your code, I've taken snippets that should help you work out where to inject my logic in relation to your own.

Loops are the easiest way in my opinion.

```
Dim objCell As Range, strWinners As String

winnumber = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range(Rng))

For Each objCell In Range(Rng)
    If objCell.Value = winnumber Then
        ' You've found a winner, now do something with this cell or those
        ' adjacent.
        
        ' I'm assuming that the winners name is in the column right next
        ' to the number that indicates they are a winner.
        strWinners = strWinners & ", " & objCell.Offset(0, -1).Text
    End If
Next

MsgBox (strWinners & " have won with " & winumber & " points!")
```

`strWinners` is the value that will store all of the winners names.

`Offset` is a way to get data from adjacent cells like you were asking about.

I hope that helps anyway.